# Is there a drug that can encapsulate benzene in the liver?

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs, pharmacology

I'm doing a project on the prevention of leukemia and upon researching on the metabolism of benzene in the liver (since high levels of benzene can lead to leukemia), I thought of a question that was puzzling to me:

Is there a drug that can encapsulate benzene in the liver until the benzene is released through urination or defecation(pooping)?

Thanks

Comment: Most drugs can't break apart benzene. It's incredibly stable.

Comment: Well, it is actually its epoxide which causes cancer. If benzene was to be so dramatically stable it will induce less harm.

Comment: @Alchimista I'm pretty sure you don't need a drug to convert benzene into an epoxide. There's enough biochemicals in the body that can do that.

Comment: @Pritt Balagopal. Yeah, that is why! :) I just said that benzene is archetypal for its special stability, not for being almost a noble compound (see comment by Melanie). By the way, the OP would like to isolate benzene from the body, not destroying it :)

Comment: The OP is seeking a sort of benzene sequestration, though wasn't that clear.

Comment: @Alchimista Yeah I was just making an extra point. But here in `By the way, the OP would like to isolate benzene from the body, not destroying it` I don't think so. He/She is just studying leukemia prevention and was looking for a chemical that can *encapsulate* (is that right?) benzene to prevent biochemical action on it. Besides, with all that petroleum around, trying to obtain benzene from human blood? Unlikely.

Comment: Yes. Extra point not needed as far I concerne, as I said that. The same is for that he would like to encapsulates benzene, to prevent exactly epoxydation or whatever causes cancer. I do not see see reasons for much discussion. I just corrected a strong unmotivated comment. Still

Comment: You took "isolate" like at the bench :) we were saying the same

Comment: I edited my question in case it was too confusing. Thanks